# Raspbian redirect console log to usb file

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspbian, console.log

I am new here, but I have spent several days in and issue that I have not solved yet.
This is what I want to achieve:

- I would like to redirect the console logs to a USB file directly.
- I have a shell script to be launched automatically when booting the raspberry (this process works). The script executes a javascript file.
- I need to remove the USB drive directly, with the raspberry pi still powered on, and the log file remaining in the USB drive.

This is what I tried:

- Redirect it directly with expression like: "sudo node node_modules/sensortag/.. > /media/USBname/Data.txt" (it shows me 'access denied'), but the first part of the expression works fine if executed without the redirection part.
- I have tried to change permissions for USB directory, and still the same problem.
- I have tried to execute the previous command in the terminal (not with the script) and it only works if "sudo su" command is entered before the instruction (but it does not work only with "sudo" command and I do not know how to insert "sudo su" command in the script). I have tried many different options.

**Do you know why I have this error? and could you tell me how to solve it?**

Another option that I can try, but not yet because I do not have it clear, is to modify the javascript file to redirect the console log to a USB file. **Could you tell me how to do it?**

Thanks a lot. I have took a look to many different forum threads but I am not able to solve this problem. I hope you can guide me on it.

Comment: are you using console.log() to write error and so to have some log of you application ? If yes with nodejs it's better to use a package called Winston. And if you want to do it by hand, you just need to read and write inside a file using writeStream